# Evaluating math expressions in a string using regex to split the string

Tags: java, regex, string

I need some with evaluating math expressions in a string.

As of now my code will work for only positive numbers.

I used regex to split the string into two separate arrays. I was able to split all the math signs in one array and all the numbers in the other. But I am unsure how to do it for negative numbers. (I dont understand the regex i just put stuff and it worked but not for negative numbers)

Anyways here is my code, Thanks in advance!`

```
    boolean mybool = true;
    String str = "1.0+2.0+3.0+4.0";
    String[] numarray = str.split("[-+/%*]");
    String[] signarray = str.split("[0123456789.]");
    double result = 0.0;
    double num1 = 0.0;
    double num2 = 0.0;

    String mystr = "";

    //Adds each element in sign array to mystr
    for(String e : signarray){
        if(e != ""){
            mystr+=e;
        }
    }

    //Assign signarray new size of length mystr
    signarray = new String[mystr.length()];


    //Cycle through each element in str and add it to signarray
    for(int i = 0; i < mystr.length(); i++){
        signarray[i] = mystr.charAt(i)+"";
    }

    //Print each element in num array
    System.out.print("Print each element in number array: ");
    for(String e : numarray){
        System.out.print(e+ " ");
    }
    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("Print each element in sign array: ");
    //print each element in sign array
    for(String e : signarray){
        System.out.print(e+ " ");
    }
    System.out.println();

    //Prints each element in sign array and element value
    for(int i = 0; i < signarray.length; i++){
        System.out.println("SignArray[" + i + "] = " + signarray[i]);
    }


    for(int i = 2; i <= numarray.length; i++){

        //this will get the first two indexes of number array
        //and store them in num1 and num1 then i use another if
        //statement to go sign array to get a sign to evaluate the
        //two nums and store the value in result.
        //hopefully you understand my logic
        if(mybool == true){


            num1 = Double.parseDouble(numarray[0]);
            num2 = Double.parseDouble(numarray[1]);
            System.out.println("num1 = " + num1);
            System.out.println("num2 = " + num2);


            if(signarray[0].equals("+")){
                result = num1 + num2;
                System.out.println("Result = num1 + num2 = " + num1 + "+" + num2 + "= " + result );
            } else if(signarray[0].equals("-")){
                result = num1 - num2;
                System.out.println("Result = num1 - num2 = " + num1 + "-" + num2 + "= " + result );
            } else if(signarray[0].equals("/")){
                result = num1 / num2;
                System.out.println("Result = num1 / num2 = " + num1 + "/" + num2 + "= " + result );
            } else if(signarray[0].equals("*")){
                result = num1 * num2;
                System.out.println("Result = num1 * num2 = " + num1 + "*" + num2 + "= " + result );
            } else if(signarray[0].equals("%")){
                result = num1 % num2;
                System.out.println("Result = num1 % num2 = " + num1 + "%" + num2 + "= " + result );
            }

            mybool = false;

        } else {

            num2 = Double.parseDouble(numarray[i-1]);
            System.out.println("Num2 = " + num2);


            if(signarray[i-2].equals("+")){
                result = result + num2;
                System.out.println("Result after math is : " + result);

            } else if(signarray[i-2].equals("-")){
                result = result - num2;
                System.out.println("Result after math is : " + result);
            } else if(signarray[i-2].equals("/")){
                result = result / num2;
                System.out.println("Result after math is : " + result);
            } else if(signarray[i-2].equals("*")){
                result = result * num2;
                System.out.println("Result after math is : " + result);
            } else if(signarray[i-2].equals("%")){
                result = result % num2;
                System.out.println("Result after math is : " + result);
            }

        }



    }`
```

Output:

```
Print each element in number array: 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 
Print each element in sign array: + + + 
SignArray[0] = +
SignArray[1] = +
SignArray[2] = +
num1 = 1.0
num2 = 2.0
Result = num1 + num2 = 1.0+2.0= 3.0
Num2 = 3.0
Result after math is : 6.0
Num2 = 4.0
Result after math is : 10.0
```

eventually i wanna be able to evaluate a string like this 
//String str = "3.01+2.2/4.01*7.1%4.0--2.0";

but i dont know how to get negative numbers from sting and store in the num array.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: -- thould throw -(-2) would be nice

Comment: I would investigate positive and negative lookbehinds for your regex. Or better yet, don't use regex use a parser.

Comment: If you _split_ on the sign, you'd never get the sign. Furthermore, `--2.0` is `-1 * -2.0`

Comment: You should not use a regular expressions for this. You need a proper scanner and then an expression parser. Throw it all away and look up the Disjkstra Shunting-yard algorithm or recursive descent expression parsing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ideally, you should use a parser instead of regex. However given your current requirements, it would be simple to use positive and negative lookbehinds.

(1). Operators are always preceded by a decimal number. So we split the arguments by matching any operator which appears after a decimal number (positive lookbehind).

```
String[] arguments = str.split("(?<=\\d)[-+/%*]");
```

(2). Arguments may start with an optional minus sign but are never preceded by another decimal number. So we split the operators by matching arguments not after a decimal number (negative lookbehind).

```
String[] operators = str.split("(?<!\\d)-?[0-9.]+");
```

Note however that there will be an empty operator at position 0 of the array. If you want to avoid this then there are many different methods you could use instead of String.split.